# How to return columns with with similar names in a dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a table that looks something like:

```
+----------------------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| ExperienceModifier|ApplicationId | ExperienceModifier|RatingModifierId | ExperienceModifier|ActionResults |
+----------------------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
|                                  |                                     |                                  |
+----------------------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

I would like to grab all of the columns that lead with 'ExperienceModifier' and stuff the results of that into its own dataframe. How would I accomplish this with pandas?

Comment: `df.columns` is a list that you can filter, Something like `new_col = [col for col in df.columns if 'ExperienceModifier' in col]`. Then pass that filtered list to your dataframe: `df[new_col]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`pandas.DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html)

```py
df.filter(like='ExperienceModifier')
```

If you want to get columns only contains `ExperienceModifier` at the beginning.

```py
df.filter(regex='^ExperienceModifier')
```

Answer (score 1):

Ynjxsjmh's answer will get all columns that contain "ExperienceModifier". If you literally want columns that *start* with that string, rather merely contain it, you can do `new_df = df[[col for col in df.columns if col[:18] == 'ExperienceModifier']]`. If all of the desired columns have `|` after "ExperienceModifier", you could also do `new_df = df[[col for col in df.columns if col.split('|')[0] == 'ExperienceModifier']]`. All of these will create a view of the dataframe. If you want a completely separate dataframe, you should copy it, like this: `new_df = df[[col for col in df.columns if col.split('|')[0] == 'ExperienceModifier']].copy()`. You also might want to create a multi-index by splitting the column names on `|` rather than creating a separate dataframe.

Comment: Thank you so much for adding extra nuance. I'll look into multi-indexes :)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer does easly the job but I still attach my "hand made version" that works:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

lst = [[1, 2, 3, 4],[1, 2, 3, 4],[1, 2, 3, 4]]
column_names = [['ExperienceModifier|ApplicationId', 'ExperienceModifier|RatingModifierId', 'ExperienceModifier|ActionResults','OtherName|ActionResults']] 

data = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns = column_names) 
data


old_and_dropped_dataframes = []
new_dataframes=[]    
for i in np.arange(0,len(column_names[0])):
    column_names[0][i].split("|")
    splits=re.findall(r"[\w']+", column_names[0][i])
    if "ExperienceModifier" in splits:
        new_dataframe = data.iloc[:,[i]]
        new_dataframes.append(new_dataframe)
    else:
        old_and_dropped_dataframe =  data.iloc[:,[i]]
        old_and_dropped_dataframes.append(old_and_dropped_dataframe)



ExperienceModifier_dataframe = pd.concat(new_dataframes,axis=1)
ExperienceModifier_dataframe

OtherNames_dataframe = pd.concat(old_and_dropped_dataframes,axis=1)
OtherNames_dataframe
```

This script creates two new dataframes starting from the initial dataframe: one that contains the columns whose names start with *ExperienceModifier* and an other one that contains the columns that do not start with *ExperienceModifier*.